# Please give an example in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ of a set that satisfies the upper bound in the Kuratowski Closure-Complement Theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, euclidean-geometry

Please give an example in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $ of a set $ T $ that satisfies the upper bound of $ 14 $ in the Kuratowski Closure-Complement Theorem. Thanks!

Comment: You may wish to refer to my answer in the following thread: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315252/how-to-prove-that-textint-textcla-textcl-textinta/315276#315276.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard example in $ \mathbb{R} $ is
$$
(0,1) \cup (1,2) \cup \{ 3 \} \cup [(4,5) \cap \mathbb{Q}].
$$

You can refer to the Wikipedia article on the [Kuratowski Closure-Complement Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem).

Comment: However, the OP is asking for an example in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Is it trivial to construct such one from that in $\mathbb{R}$?