# $A \subset \Bbb R$ such that $A$, $clA$, $int(A)$, $cl(int(A))$, $int(clA)$ are pairwise distinct

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Do there exist subsets with internal closures $A$ of $\mathbb R$ such that $A$ , $\bar A$ , $A^\circ$ , $(\bar A)^\circ$ , $\overline{A^\circ}$ are pairwise distinct?

I found an example from a book that such a set exists. For example, consider $$A=[0,1)\cup (1,2]\cup(\mathbb Q\cap [3,4])\cup\{5\}$$

My question on this example is here:

$$\bar A=[0,1]\cup[1,2]\cup[3,4]\cup\{5\}$$

$$ A^\circ\subset(0,1)\cup(1,2) $$

$$ \overline{A^\circ}\subset[0,1]\cup[1,2]=[0,2] $$

$$ (\bar A)^\circ\subset (0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup (3,4) $$

But, from these how can I say they are all pairwise distinct?

Otherwise cite an another examples regarding these conditions?

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: $A$ and $\bar A$ will never be disjoint. Although, $A^o$ and $\partial A$ are disjoint.

Comment: They are pairwise distinct. I.e. no two sets are the same. What they are not is pairwise disjoint, but as Matthew points out that can't happen no matter what. $A$ and $\bar{A}$ will never be disjoint unless $A=\emptyset$.

Comment: Look carefully, it is "distinct", not "disjoint". @Matthew Levy

Comment: How can you say that they are pairwise distinct? please explain it.@DRF

Comment: The sets $ A_1,A_2,\dots,A_n$ are pairwise disjoint means $A_i \cap A_j =\emptyset \ \forall \ i ,j \leq n \ \& \ i \neq j.$  For any $A \subset  \mathbb  R ,\  A^0 \subset A \subset \overline{A}$

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I should have read more carefully.

Comment: You’ll find [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315252/how-to-prove-that-textint-textcla-textcl-textinta/315276#315276) useful.

Comment: I don't think you need the ${\bf Q}\cap [3,4]$ part is needed. Take just $A=[0,1)\cup (1,2]\cup\{5\}$ and draw pictures of all these sets.

Comment: @ tomasz):That may be..But my question is that how we find that they are **distinct** ? As $A^0\subset.....$ not $=$

Comment: @  Berrick Fillmore ): In [your suggested question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315252/how-to-prove-that-textint-textcla-textcl-textinta/315276#315276) I found the example which I already know  but NOT the explanation in the answer ..

Comment: Pairwise DISTINCT  means they are UNEQUAL. The subset relation in each of the last 3 lines should be an equals-sign.So there are indeed 5 different sets..... BTW, the most  number of distinct sets you can get starting with some subset X of a space S, by iterations of "complement" and "closure" is 14, including X. (Hint :  Int (Cl(X))=Int(Cl(Int(Cl(X)))) and Cl(Int(X)) =Cl(Int(Cl(Int(X)))).  You can get 14 for some subset of reals but I dk how.